# How to start Apache server in xampp on Ubuntu?

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp, xampp

I've successfully installed lampp and xampp on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. But when I start xampp with the command `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` the Apache server does not start.

when starting the server:
[image: when starting the server]

when stopping the service:
[image: when stopping the service]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when not needed. If you put the error messages in your question it is easier for us to help you. Both by users (select -> google) and the platform itself (by showing similar questions). (And if screenshots are really the best way, don't forget to use the image tag instead of a normal link.)